как вытащить данные из дистрибутива wsl
windows 11 wsl2 обновился перестал определяться wsl. вопрос можно ли как то вытащить данные по проектам из дистрибутивов ubuntu&

https://superuser.com/q/1185033 оно?

WSL "хранилище" по сути где то в папке виндового пользователя. Вроде в AppData. Восстанавливайте именно всю информацию  виндового пользователя.Если он забекаплен то супер,  если нет -  рекавери тулзы берите и пробуйте.  Если информация очень важная - несите специалистам.
